# Does Accumulo actually need all Zookeeper servers listed?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, consul, accumulo

Accumulo's documentation clearly expects that all ZooKeeper servers should be listed in the setting `instance.zookeeper.host` inside both **accumulo-site.xml** and **client.conf**.  Is a single load-balanced ZooKeeper hostname sufficient for either (or both) of these settings?  Or are there reasons to prefer an explicit list of all ZooKeeper hosts?  I expect them to be practically equivalent - not just in initially running but also in performance for a sizeable cluster.

The Accumulo documentation doesn't go into sufficient detail on what specifically it does with each of the ZooKeeper servers listed.  If it simply does its own load balancing, then I should be fine to provide the single load-balanced hostname.  If there's some other magic done, then I would appreciate any insight.

I'm attempting to integrate Accumulo and some related services with a Consul service mesh.  Consul offers internal DNS resolution to configured services, e.g. ***zookeeper.service.mydatacenter.consul***, which provides rudimentary load balancing by randomly ordering the returned IP addresses of all such hosts.  There are at least a couple of options for configuring Accumulo with all of the ZooKeeper hosts, but they get into complications I'd rather avoid.  E.g. using a static set of "generic" hostnames doesn't allow us to easily change the size of the Zookeeper Cluster, or using Consul Template to dynamically list the ZooKeeper nodes brings up the need to deal with a rolling Accumulo cluster restart (which has a whole host of complications).  I'm also open to alternative suggestions.

**Note**: This question is not specifically about the Consul service mesh, as it's simply the mechanism I'm using for load balancing (or alternatively for listing the ZooKeeper servers).  I'm most interested in the advantages or disadvantages of configuring Accumulo with a single load-balanced ZooKeeper hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZooKeeper servers operate as a coordinated group, where the group as a whole determines the value of a field at any given time, based on consensus among the servers. If you have a 5-node ZooKeeper instance running, all 5 server names are relevant. You should not simply treat them as 5 redundant 1-node instances. Accumulo, and other ZooKeeper clients, actually use all of the servers listed. More information at https://zookeeper.apache.org

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with ZooKeeper (though not yet as much as I'd prefer for what I'm doing), but I think you got to the heart of my question.  I'm primarly wondering whether you can effectively deal with a single ZooKeeper node (via load balancing) and let ZooKeeper internally handle consensus, but it sounds like that concept may be fundamentally flawed.  So every ZooKeeper client must know about the entire ZooKeeper cluster in order for it to work correctly as intended?  There's no abstraction of the rest of the cluster in this way?

Comment: Assuming that Accumulo doesn't act differently than a standard ZooKeeper client, the ZooKeeper FAQ specifically says that Round Robin DNS load balancing is fully supported.  In fact, it sounds like it's effectively treated as an alternative to explicitly listing all hosts in the client config, as the client will accept the DNS response of IP addresses and proceed as though they were listed in the client.conf.  At least, that's how I read it - and some searching around seems to indicate that's correct.  Consul DNS is technically not "round robin" but should be near enough to the same.

Comment: Here's a link to the ZK FAQ entry.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/FAQ#FAQ-CanIrunanensembleclusterbehindaloadbalancer%3F

Comment: Accumulo does act differently than a standard ZK client in its monitor service, at least, because it tries to display status of all ZK servers in the quorum. This may not be important for you.

From the linked confluence, I think the short answer is: it might work (not something I would have guessed)... there might be drawbacks, such as failure handling and reconfiguration. I wouldn't recommend it for Accumulo, because that's not a typical deployment in my experience, and it's certainly not a standard test case upstream, but I don't know any specific reason why it shouldn't work.